# Is it possible to write a generic function to extract an enum's associated value in Swift?

Tags: generics, swift, enums

Take the following `enum` as an example:

```
enum Property {
    case Editable(Bool)
    case StringValue(String)
}
```

I can write a function using a `switch` statement that will extract the associated value like this:

```
get() -> Any {
    switch self {
        case .Editable(let value): return value
        case .StringValue(let value): return value
}
```

But if I have an `enum` with lots of different `cases`, it'd be much simpler to write a generic function, like this:

```
get<T>() -> T {
    switch self {
        case (What Goes Here?)(let value): return value
}
```

In other words, it would be a generic function where the case always returns whatever value it holds... but I can't get it to work.

As far as I can tell, a `switch` statement is the only way to get at the associated value, but I can't formulate an appropriate `switch x` - `case x` pattern that will just return whatever value is held.

Any suggestions?

Is there some fundamental principle of `enums` that I'm violating by even trying to do this?

Comment: I'm afraid that the `case let` pattern is the only to extract associated values. This is because each case _is_ a different case (and could have a different kind of value, etc.). If you're finding this inconvenient, I would question your choice of an enum with associated values to start with.

Comment: Yes, I am beginning to question my choice as wel... The reason i wanted to do it is because I can create an array of these "properties" - they are all of the same type even though the associated values are of different types. Then I can process the array using map, reduce, filter, etc.

Comment: You can create an array of Bool, Int, String, etc. as an array of AnyObject (or Any), so I don't see how having it be an enum is helping you here. In fact it seems to me that it just hurting you. :)

Comment: Yes, I have looked at that approach as well. A dictionary is another approach. But an enum with associated values is still an interesting way to pass around values of different types, and generic functions are ideal for handling different types, so I am just exploring the limits of combining enums and generic functions. I am realizing that there are substantial limitations.

Comment: It's impossible because different cases may have the same type.

Comment: That shouldn't be the cause of the problem… A generic function ought to be able to return whatever type is stored in *that particular case*. The fact that another case stores the same type of associated value should effect the ability of the function to return a value. The function is called by an instance of the enum on itself, so there is only one value being considered at a time...